# javascript RegExp: how to match multiline and closetag

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

```
var ex = /(<script\s?[^>]*>)([\s\S]*)(<\/script>)/;
//Note: here is 2 script tags
var str = '<script>\nvar x=0;\n</script>\n<div>\nhtml\n</div>\n<script>var y=0;\n</script>'
str.replace(ex, function(full, prefix, script, suffix) {
    return prefix + doSomething(script) + suffix;
})
```

But I got wrong script: `var x=0;</script><div>..</div><script>var y=0;`

What I want is: `var x=0;` and `var y=0;`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use regex like below:

```
<script>([\s\S]*?)</script>
```

In Javascript we cannot make `.`  dotall so we use the [\s\S] character class which matches any character either whitespace or not whitespace including newline. `?` is for non-greedy match so that you don't nest script tags.

Comment: ridgerunner is also correct, but you explain what `?` does, thanks.

Comment: @guilin 桂林 - I had already mentioned that. `?` means in that case *? matches 0 or more of the preceeding token and will match as few characters as possible before satisfying the next token. So something like `<script><script></script></script>` won't match in whole.

Comment: No need for capture groups around start and end tags. Also should allow for attributes within the start tag. Otherwise, much better without the lookbehind. +1

Answer (score 3):

This function matches `SCRIPT` elements contents and returns the strings in an array:

```js
// Return an array of <script> elements contents. 
function getScriptsConntents(text) {
    var scripts = [];
    var m;
    var re = /<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/ig;
    while (m = re.exec(text)) {
        scripts.push(m[1]);
    }
    return scripts;
}
```